# Html table won't print full width

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

Help, trying to print a calendar using html table, prints fine on mac but windows, all browsers, it's putting a 3" margin at top no matter what the CSS print settings. Client wants calendar to print full bleed. I can get it to print full size if I adjust the print settings on the browser to not be shrink to fit and then set it to 110% but that solution screws up the type and messes with the characters in the calendar. Is there any way to do it using straight CSS?

Comment: have you tried with @page { size: auto;  margin: 0mm; } ?

Comment: yes i have tried it and have tried different margin settings, page sizes, I can get it to look worse but never better. thank you!

Comment: can u share your html

Comment: Hi Deepak! I'm bound by an NDA and can't share the html. Was hoping to get an answer without having to disclose. Thank you!

Comment: can you trie **width: 100%;**

Comment: You should have to use **overflow: hidden;** property to fit. I think its would be work.

Comment: Arshiya, my issue is filling the page, not overflowing the page. The calendar currently is not full height and width when it goes to print and I'd like it to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this simple Javascript code to print the calendar

```js
<script language="javascript">
function Clickheretoprint()
{ 
  var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
      disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=400, height=400, left=100, top=25"; 
  var content_vlue = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML; 
  
  var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
   docprint.document.open(); 
   docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title>'); 
   docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()" style="width: 800px; font-size:12px; font-family:arial;">');          
   docprint.document.write(content_vlue);          
   docprint.document.write('</body></html>'); 
   docprint.document.close(); 
   docprint.focus(); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<a href="javascript:Clickheretoprint()">Print</a>
<div id="print_content" style="width: 100%;">
Calendar/html table goes here
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I'm not having difficulty printing it, it's printing. The difficulty comes in getting the calendar to be full height and width. Thank you!

Comment: I would love to see the HTML codes but you said you are bound by an NDA. There is really not much I can do.